# Jboss WS Inbound message

Tags: java, jboss7.x, ws-security

I have a Jboss WS with WS-Security in wsdl. Is there some way to capture inbound message when a security validation (like timestamp or cert) have fired?

Regards.

Comment: Use a SOAP Handler which is the normal way to log the message body.

Comment: Thanks, i have tested it and works good.